# What would "correr" be in third person?

Tags: gramática, conjugación

Recently, I learned how to conjugate Spanish verbs that end in -ar. (camin**ar**, pin**tar**, trabaj**ar**, etc.) However, I never learned how to conjugate a verb that ends in -er.

I know that 'caminar' in third person would turn into 'camina.' For example: "Ella *camina* en el parque.

What would 'correr' be in third person? For example:

> Ella *fill in with correct answer* en el parque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just "corre":

> Ella corre en el parque

The verb correr is conjugated as follows:

```
              SINGULAR    PLURAL
1st person    corro       corremos
2nd    "      corres      corréis
3rd    "      corre       corren
```

You can also get the [full conjugation](http://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/conjugacion/237-correr.html) in this link.

Comment: I would add corren. Uses in some parts of Spain and America.

Comment: @Jaime you mean "ustedes corren" as 2nd person, right?